# how to send empty file to server using android VolleyMultipart

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data, http-status-code-500

I have a problem while Updating my profile with empty profile photo. I am getting 500 error while sending request. 
here is my postman data[image]

below is my Code

hashMap.put("categoryId", String.valueOf(myAdvertisementModelObject.getCategoryId()));
   hashMap.put("discountPercentage", discount);
   hashMap.put("description", description);

```
        HashMap<String, List<File>> fileMap = new HashMap();

                List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (finalFile.exists()) {
                    fileList.add(finalFile);
                } else {
                    fileList.add(null);
                }
                if (!finalFile.exists()) {
                    fileMap.put("file", fileList);
                } else {
                    fileMap.put("file", fileList);

                }
    VolleyHelperMultiPart.postMultipartMultipleFiles(getActivity(), Constants.UPDATE_EXISTED_DISCOUNTED_OFFER,
                                hashMap, 0, null, fileMap,
                                Constants.REQUEST_OFFERING_FREE_OFFER, null);
```

below is my volley helper class

```
 public static void postMultipartMultipleFiles(final Context context, String serverUrl,
                                              final Map<String, String> params, int fileType,
                                              final Map<String, String> authenticationHeaders,
                                              final Map<String, List<File>> fileMap,
                                              final String reqType, final String localId) {

    try {

        if (NetWorkConnection.isConnected()) {

            if (!reqType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.NOTIFICATION_UPLOAD_INTENT_SERVICE_FILES_REQUEST)) {
                progressDialog = Utilities.showProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
            final String url = Constants.SERVER_URL + serverUrl;

            System.out.println("========server url was============" + url);

            MultipartAPI multipartAPI = new MultipartAPI(url, params, authenticationHeaders, fileType, fileMap, reqType,
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
```

below is MultipartApi class

public MultipartAPI(String url, final Map params, final Map secureHeaders, int fileType,
                        final Map> fileParams, String reqType,
                        Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener listener) {

```
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
    mParams = params;
    msecureHeaders = secureHeaders;
    this.fileType = fileType;
    mFileParams = fileParams;
    this.reqType = reqType;
    mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    buildMultipartEntity();
}


/**
 * AuthFailureError
 *
 * @return
 * @throws AuthFailureError
 */
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

    if (msecureHeaders != null) {
        return msecureHeaders;
    } else {
        return super.getHeaders();
    }
}

/**
 * @return
 */
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return mBodyContentType;
}


@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        System.out.println("getting Body MultiPart----->");
        HttpEntity entity = mBuilder.build();
        mBodyContentType = entity.getContentType().getValue();
        entity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e(e.getMessage());
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

/**
 *
 */
private void buildMultipartEntity() {

    if (mParams != null) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mParams.entrySet()) {
            mBuilder.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    //System.out.println("Building MultiPart----->" + mFileParams.size());

    if (mFileParams != null) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> entry : mFileParams.entrySet()) {

            List<File> listFiles = entry.getValue();
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file == null) {
                    Log.d("tag", "my condition");
                  mBuilder.addPart("file",new FileBody(new File(""),ContentType.create("image/jpg"),"") );
               //    mBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new File(""), ContentType.create("image/jpg"), "");
                } else {
                    if (reqType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_UPLOAD_RESPONSE)) {

                        if (fileType == 1) {
                            System.out.println("========================Image uploading");
                            mBuilder.addBinaryBody(entry.getKey(), file, ContentType.create("image/jpg"),
                                    file.getName());
                            System.out.println("=========get key======" + entry.getKey());

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
                            mBuilder.addBinaryBody(entry.getKey(), file, ContentType.create("image/jpg"),
                                    file.getName());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
}
```

Getting 500 error

```
  E/Volley: [803] MultipartAPI.getBody: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)


 E/Volley: [803] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 

=======error response========dfbrgbvra======<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Required request part 'file' is not present</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</h3></body></html>
```

Please some one help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: That requires file not null, BTW null and Empty is two different things, so you should send empty/blank file instead of null

Comment: @AlNoman,  If I send it like  mBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new File(""), ContentType.create("image/jpg"), ""); again getting 500 error

Comment: first of all volley is not for large file uploads, and you can add a simple if() condition to skip it if file is not selected

Comment: @basha 500 is internal server error not volley's, please check your server that is it really accept blank/empty file.

Comment: @AlNoman, it is working in postman .it is receiving blank file also,. problem is from my side

Comment: @Nilabja, I have written this statement in if condition. have to add a field as file as headers along with other fileds as shown in above postman picture in my question. for that I am using **addBinary** Method

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @Nilabja, I have edited  my question . Please check it

Comment: new File("") does not creates any file, I suggest you "    mBuilder.addPart("file",new FileBody(new File(""),ContentType.create("image/jpg"),"") );" just remove this line and execute

Comment: its a 400 error while removing that line

Comment: can you post the raw response for error 400?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161283/discussion-between-basha-and-nilabja).